# Touch detection of SKSpriteNode with child nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to trigger a touch event on a SKSpriteNode where it's child node is tapped on. When the child node it touched, the event isn't triggered. I have found a hack work around using `.parent` but doesn't feel like the most efficient or elegant way of doing is.

Please see code below:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if node is PlanListItem || node.parent is PlanListItem {

        for plan in planListItems as [PlanListItem] {
            plan.selected = false
        }

        // Some more code...
    }
}
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: add the following one line code in your touchesBegan. so that the action will be send it to nextResponder(superview)==>  self.nextResponder()?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM, this is SpriteKit, not UIKit

Comment: @shahidaltaf,  could you explain a bit more.  How big is the child compared to the parent?  Is it possible to touch the parent and not the child?  (I am trying to assume you have a big fat mamma,  and inside of said mamma are 3 children,  you touch the children, and mamma does something, but if you touch mamma, nothing happens)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so, using your analogy, mamma has one child, child is 50% the size of mamma but centered evenly. Touching mamma or child should invoke the same event. Make sense?

Comment: Oh if touching mama or child fires the same event,  then turn off userinteraction on child and turn it on for mamma only

Comment: Simone does have the answer you need after your clarification

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Please see my comment to Simone's answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this inside the node subclass:

```
class PlanListItem:SKSpriteNode {

    var isSelected: Bool = false
    override init(texture size etc) {
        //your init
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("PlanListItem touched")
        isSelected = !isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a parent class which contains multiple PlanListItem objects. Currently, this parent class catches the touch event and deselects all the PlanListItem's, and then reselects the one which is touched. For that reason, I cannot put the touch capture on the PlanListItem subclass. This isn't really a solution to my issue. My problem is to allow the class and its child classes to trigger the touch event.

Comment: Do you not understand how subclassing works?  Just make a new child class called PlanListItemChild that extends PlanListItem, and turn off userInteractionEnables in this class. (Or just make the child SKSpriteNodes,  no idea why they are what you want them to be)

Comment: To solve your deselect issue,  use NSNotifications to post a message telling all PlanListItems to turn off,  then just turn on the one after

Comment: @Knight0fDragonthe children are SKSpriteNode subclasses, and yes, I do understand how they work. I will however look into the NSNotification approach. Thanks